# Image from static folder doesn't appear when it is not login state [Spring MVC & Thymeleaf]

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Within my home page, I am using img tag where the source is from a static folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th="http://thymeLeaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!-- <html xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"> -->

<head>
    <title> Home </title>

    <object th:include="fragments/fragment :: css" th:remove="tag"></object>
    <object th:include="fragments/fragment :: js" th:remove="tag"></object>
</head>

<body>
    <nav th:replace="fragments/fragment :: navbar"></nav>
    <img style="width: 100% ; background-size: cover;" th:src="@{/img/webconstruction.png}">


    </body>
</html>


    </body>
```

and this is my fragment

```
<head>
        <title> Home </title>
        <head th:fragment="css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}">
        </head>

        <!-- jquery, ajax, and bootstrap.js -->
        <head th:fragment="js">
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script th:src="@{/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
        </head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header th:fragment="navbar">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #9be3de;">
                <a class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1" th:href="@{/}">SIKOPERASI</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/home}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span> </a>
                        </li>
                        <li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/anggota}">Anggota</a>
                        </li>
                        <li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pinjaman</a>
                        </li>

                        <li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"   class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/simpanan}">Simpanan</a>

                        </li>
                        <li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/register}">Register</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" th:text="Logout">
                        <a th:href="@{/logout}"></a>
                    </button> -->
                    <div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
                    <div class="navbar-nav pull-right">
                        <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/api/user}" th:text="${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}"></a>
<!--                        <div style="padding-top: 10px ; padding-right: 20px" th:text="${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}"></div>-->
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link active btn btn-danger" th:href="@{/logout}">Logout</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()">
                        <div class="navbar-nav pull-right">
                            <a class="nav-item nav-link active btn btn-primary" th:href="@{/login}">Login</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
</body>
</html>
```

I have looked around whether if there is an error on my understanding regarding using an image from a folder in thymeleaf, and there is nothing wrong with it. Yet this is what I got.

When I first open my localhost, it will redirect me to a not-login state like this:
[image: Not logged in homepage]

As you can see, the image got an error like that. I tried to login and when I log in, the page should have been redirected to the home page that shows the authenticated fragments. However, this is what I got:

[image: after login]

It is not something that I want. However, when I manually retype localhost:2017/home, it will redirect me to the page that I was hoping to see.
[image]

This is my websecurityconfig:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/home").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll();
    }
```

What I want is to make the image appear when it is still not in login state and after login, it will redirect to the last image instead of the second image. This is how my folder looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as per your configuration I can see that `img` path is not in `permitAll` list.

Which means you wont be able to access any img resource without login in.

So you see img error as described in your post.

Since your img url was last one being triggered before giving error, on login it will redirect to same url after login.

Thus you see Under Construction page.

How to resolve it?

You can add your /img path in permitAll list or atleast the one with Under Construction.

```
.antMatchers("/img/**").permitAll()
```